# How to display number of sunday's between the dates on the ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying build app on ReactJS to display number of Sundays between the dates when click on submit button. I've take start date and end date as input date and button in side a form. I'm unable to get an idea how to incorporate in submitHandler and display. Below is my code

```
 import React from 'react'
    import {useState} from 'react'
    
    const Calculate = () => {
      const [inputDate,setInputDate] = useState({
        sdate:'',
        edate:'',
      });
      
      const onChangeHandler = (e)=>{
          let name =e.target.name
          let value = e.target.value
    
    
        const Calculate = () => {
          const [inputDate,setInputDate] = useState({
            sdate:'',
            edate:'',
          });
          
          const onChangeHandler = (e)=>{
              let name =e.target.name
              let value = e.target.value
              setInputDate({...inputDate,[name]:value})
          }
          const submitHandler=(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            
          }
    
          return (
            <div>
              <form action="">
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="sdate"  onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="">End Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="edate" onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>
                  <button>Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          )
        }
    
        export default Calculate
    
    <!-- end snippet -->
    
          setInputDate({...inputDate,[name]:value})
      }
      const submitHandler=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <form action="">
            <div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="">Start Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="sdate"  onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="">End Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="edate" onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
              </div>
              <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Calculate
```

Looking for help here. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what is the question. To display anything in react you have to use state.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Konrad Linkowski. I got the solution for this